# Apply Google Apps Script Array into HTML form autocomplete datalist

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, google-apps-script

I have managed to make a Google Scripts function that creates an array from a Google Sheet column filtering out any spaces. However, I'm not sure how to pass this variable to my HTML form so that I can create an autocomplete options list.

Users will be adding content to spreadsheet so the list has to be dynamic to grow with the spreadsheet. Forms user should be able to type with autocomplete or scroll from the list of items in the spreadsheet array that will change over time.

Edit: sorry for any confusion by not showing enough code. Basically I'm trying to get the array in readData() to turn into something like this in html

```
<datalist id="datalist">
<option value="Plain#1">
<option value="Plain#2">
<option value="Plain#3">
<option value="Plain#4">
<option value="Plain#5">
<option value="Plain#6">
  </datalist>
```

[image: result I'm looking but adjusts to amount of items in the spreadsheet]

Code follows:

Here is my JS

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

  }
</script>
```

Here is my GS

```
function readData() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ftdM8esHXRbdNbN0I00GSMPj5ZiCcPo9cs_9dAjFldc/edit#gid=540792552;" 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Bags Inventory");
  var rng = ws.getRange(2,2,350,1)
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
  var filArray = rangeArray.filter(function (el) {
  return el != "";
});
return(filArray);
}

function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PRS5O42_vAwEqLFjULu-SyPvzSR902tu9xMXA88WnWM/edit#gid=73972270;"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  ws.appendRow([
                new Date(), 
                Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                formObject.item1,
                formObject.amount1,
                formObject.item2,
                formObject.amount2,
                formObject.item3,
                formObject.amount3,
                formObject.item4,
                formObject.amount4,
                formObject.item5,
                formObject.amount5,
                formObject.item6,
                formObject.amount6,
                formObject.item7,
                formObject.amount7,
                formObject.item8,
                formObject.amount8,
                formObject.item9,
                formObject.amount9,
                formObject.item10,
                formObject.amount10,
                formObject.client]);
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <base target="_top">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <style>
            ::placeholder{
            color: #D3D3D3 !important;
            }
            </style>
            <?!= include('JavaScript'); 
            var options = readData();
            ?>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                            <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Paper Bag Inventory</p>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="item1">Item Code</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item1" name="item1" placeholder="Item #1" list="datalist" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="amount1">Amount</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount1" name="amount1" placeholder="Amount" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item2" name="item2" placeholder="Item #2" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount2" name="amount2" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item3" name="item3" placeholder="Item #3" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount3" name="amount3" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item4" name="item4" placeholder="Item #4" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount4" name="amount4" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item5" name="item5" placeholder="Item #5" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount5" name="amount5" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item6" name="item6" placeholder="Item #6" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount6" name="amount6" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item7" name="item7" placeholder="Item #7" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount7" name="amount7" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item8" name="item8" placeholder="Item #8" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount8" name="amount8" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item9" name="item9" placeholder="Item #9" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount9" name="amount9" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item10" name="item10" placeholder="Item #10" list="datalist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount10" name="amount10" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client" name="client" placeholder="Client Name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
    
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                        <div id="output"></div>
                  </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

    <datalist id="datalist">

            <script type="text/javascript">
            // my attempt to call gs function
              var mylist = readData()
            
              var options = '';
            
              for(var i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++)
                options += '<option value="'+mylist[i]+'" />';
            
              document.getElementById('datalist').innerHTML = options;
            </script>
   </datalist>
```

Comment: Can you share more details on how you are executing your HTML? Are you using it like Apps Script Web APP? Do you have more code on the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

### Modification points:

- In your case, I would like to recommend to return 1 dimensional array from `readData()` at Google Apps Script.
- From your HTML&Javascript, I think that your HTML file is put to the Google Apps Script project. From this situation, I would like to propose to put the values from the Spreadsheet using the templated HTML.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function readData() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ftdM8esHXRbdNbN0I00GSMPj5ZiCcPo9cs_9dAjFldc/edit#gid=540792552;" 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Bags Inventory");
  var rng = ws.getRange(2,2,350,1)
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
  var filArray = rangeArray.filter(function (el) {return el[0] != ""}).flat();  // Modified
  return filArray;
}
```

And, unfortunately, I couldn't understand the method for using the HTML in your situation. So if you are using your script as the Web Apps, please modify as follows.

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  html.data = readData();
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

- If you use sidebar, please use this.

  ```
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
    html.data = readData();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate());
  ```
- If you use dialog, please use this.

  ```
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
    html.data = readData();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(), "sample");
  ```

#### HTML&Javascript side:

From:

```
<datalist id="datalist"></datalist>
```

To:

```
<datalist id="datalist">
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <option value="<?= data[i] ?>">
<? } ?>
</datalist>
```

### Note:

- **When you use the Web Apps and you modified the script, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a autocomplete input form work like this?

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
}

/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Just replace the `countries` variable by your array requested from google sheet

Source code by https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp